# Javascript library to parse quantities of items

Tags: library, javascript, nlp

Is there a library that can preform the following transformations?

```
"5 servings" => {num: 5, name: "servings"}
"five blocks" => {num: 5, name: "blocks"}
"five and a half teasopons of sugar" => {num: 5.5, name: "teaspoons of sugar"}
"four hundred milligrams of iron" => {num: 400, name: "milligrams of iron"}
```

It would be even better if the unit could be seperated out to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a JavaScript library called **nlp_compromise**.

> **nlp_compromise** is a cool way to use natural language in javascript.

This is an open source library and its source code is available [here](https://github.com/nlp-compromise/nlp_compromise). According to your question, this library can detect a number, unit, and noun. Here are below examples that I taken from nlp_compromise documentation:

```
nlp_compromise = {
  value :{
    number: Number,      //fifty kilometers -> 50
    unit: String,        //fifty km -> km
    unit_name: String,   //fifty km -> kilometer
    measurement: String, //fifty km -> distance
  }
};
```

You also can get noun from a sentence. Please, take a look full API documentation [here](https://github.com/nlp-compromise/nlp_compromise/blob/master/docs/api.md).

Comment: It does not accept fractions or decimals

Comment: Also fails to parse 50 grams

Comment: Yes, it is. This library is actively being developed right now. You can create an issue for that as your feature request.