# Is there any library that can parse free form numbers?

Tags: library, javascript, nlp

Is there any library that can parse free form numbers?

Examples:

```
"2 million" => 2,000,000
"one-half" => 0.5
"3 ½" => 3.5
"three thousand five hundred and sixty seven" => 3567
```

Comment: In how far should it differ from your other requested library in [Javascript library to parse quantities of items](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/32093/185) – except that here the name of the item is skipped? To me it looks like the answer you've accepted there would match here as well.

Comment: @Izzy Unfortunately nlp_compromises's number parser fails for fractions and decimals

Comment: I am attempting to implement this in nlp_compromise

Comment: How much do you want to pay?  You can do this through WolframAlpha and Mathematica.

Comment: @Chenmunka I don't want to pay anything but thanks for the suggestion.